# URL-encode a URL

Tags: .net, url, urlencode

Is there a .NET encoding method I could use to encode a URL to be passed within a URL parameter?

For example say I have:

`url_of_interest = "http://asdf.asdf/asdf.htm"`

and I want to include this as one (1) URL form parameter when I do an upload to a web-application:

`http://mywebservice/upload?url=<<encoded URL here>>`

Comment: Note that C# is a programming language. It does not have encoding methods. It is the .NET Framework that has encoding methods.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httputility.urlencode.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

HttpServerUtility.UrlEncode should do the trick:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zttxte6w.aspx

Comment: I had to down vote you because you cannot create an instance of this class.

Comment: Why does it matter that an instance cannot be created? An instance is provided for you if you're running in ASP.NET.

Comment: He does not specify anywhere that he is using ASP.NET.

Comment: @ChaosPandion Feeling a little anal-rentenative today, are we? The question did not exclude ASP.NET so the answer is valid option.

Comment: @John, I have to side with ChaosPandion on this one. I came to this question looking for answers on specifically how to do this *outside* of the ASP.NET realm.

Answer (score 1):

[HttpUtility.UrlEncode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4fkewx0t.aspx)

> The UrlEncode() method can be used
>   to encode the entire URL, including
>   query-string values. If characters
>   such as blanks and punctuation are
>   passed in an HTTP stream, they might
>   be misinterpreted at the receiving
>   end. URL encoding converts characters
>   that are not allowed in a URL into
>   character-entity equivalents; URL
>   decoding reverses the encoding. For
>   example, when embedded in a block of
>   text to be transmitted in a URL, the
>   characters < and > are encoded as %3c
>   and %3e.

Answer (score 1):

You should use MS Anti XSS library's

AntiXss.UrlEncode method

The AntiXSS library can be downloaded from the following location

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=051EE83C-5CCF-48ED-8463-02F56A6BFC09&displaylang=en

Answer (score 1):

As System.Web is being decommissioned from a modern OWIN based application, the alternative solution to `HttpUtility.UrlEncode`should be `WebUtility.UrlEncode`